# Extracting Utime on Fast Report 2.5

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I wanted to extract Utime 2 types. One for AM ouput second for PM output.I learned how to create my own object but I couldn't extract from the [Utime] object.Could I use FRAC() here?To get the AM part.

here is my current ouput.

[image]

My current fast report code.

[image]

How could I extract from this object?

Comment: _"I wanted to extract Utime 2 types. One for AM ouput second for PM output."_ What is Utime, what 2 types from what? _"I learned how to create my own object but I couldn't extract from the [Utime] object.Could I use FRAC() here?To get the AM part."_ Nice, but we don't know that object, and if you mention `FRAC()`, it hardly sounds like an object, but some numeric value (maybe a date time type). You cannot anyhow convert a value that is holding PM time to AM.

Comment: I'm only guessing that [Utime] is an array as it stores all the log in and out of the user.Is there a way to determine if its array?

Comment: I guess so, `AmTime := Utime[0];`, but that assumes that `Utime` is an array of elements of data type same as `AmTime` is.

Comment: @Victoria I tried doing that.Got no result.Is it possible its just a plain string?

Comment: @Victoria So I tried using AmTime := length(Utime); and its returning a result.

Comment: `Length` can be used to query array length as well (why would one store set of time values in a string? I would geuss an array of `TTime` or `TDateTime`). Don't you have a chance to consult this with the report author?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151668/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-victoria).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you may use Frac function. Delphi's TDateTime type is double, so Frac function will return time part of TDateTime as double value

```
begin
  if frac([Utime]) < 0.5 then AmTime := [Utime] else PmTime := [Utime];
end
```

Comment: I tried this and gave me `variant could not convert variant of type string into type double`

Comment: It seems Utime is string, so, you should use StrToTime function to convert string to time or analize first two chars of Utime string  (use Copy function)

Comment: `begin
AmTime := 0;
PmTime := 0;
if frac(StrToTime([Utime])) < 0.5 then
 begin
  AmTime := [time];
  PmTime := 0;
 end;
end` something like this?

Comment: `begin
Utime := '''' + '11:13:00' + '''';
if frac(StrToTime(Utime)) < 0.5 then
  AmTime :=  '''' + Utime + '''';
end`